# Is there a possibility to use a "for loop" to access different lists?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to make changes to different lists as follows:

```
# Variable that indicates who scored a goal. Can either take value a or b.
goal = "a"

# Initiate points counter
points_a = [0]
points_b = [0]

players = ["a", "b"]

for x in players:
    if goal == x:
        points_x[0] += 1

print(points_a)
```

I would like to update the "points counter" depending on whether goal takes the value a or b but am struggling to find a way to tell Python that I am trying to access the lists within the loop. My desired output in this case, where goal is set to "a" is "[1]". At the moment I am just getting the error "NameError: name 'points_x' is not defined". Is there a way to do this in Python?

Thankful for any hints!

Manuel

Comment: `points_x` is indeed not defined in your code. Python will not magically turn `points_x` into `points_a` or `points_b` for you based on `x` - that's not how code works

Comment: Use ```dict``` to store points as ```dict-values``` and players as ```dict-keys```, ```players = {"a":0, "b":0}; players[goal] += 1```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a plain dictionary instead of two variables:

```
# Variable that indicates who scored a goal. Can either take value a or b.
goal = "a"

# Initiate points counter
player_points = { "a": 0, "b": 0 }

# no need for loop
player_points[goal] += 1

print(player_points["a"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is a mapping between a player and a their points.
You can do this through a dictionary:

```
goal = "a"
player_dict = {
    "a":[0],
    "b":[0]
}

player_dict[goal][0] += 1
```

I'm also not sure why you are using a list instead of just a single integer to store the points.

Comment: Why are the values lists?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I used lists because I am most familiar with them, but you are right. Using a simple integer works just fine.